# Combine multiple PDFs into multiple PDFs

Tags: automator, pdf

I'm trying to take a set of PDFs (that I'll have already separated into one page files) that I want to combine into multiple PDFs. As a teacher, I want to be able to scan a stack of tests into one big PDF file, split that into single pages (I already have the Automator service for that), and then combine the results into a separate file for each student. So if I had 10 students and a 4 page test, I'd want to be able to combine those 40 files into 10 separate PDFs, ideally labeled by student name (if there was a way for me to input that list of names into Automator). Worst case scenario, I just run a combinePDF service for each individual student, but I didn't know if there was a way I could do that all in one fell swoop?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd use the _third-party commandline tool_, `cpdf `, and script the entire process. Have a look at: [Coherent PDF Command Line Tools Community Release](http://community.coherentpdf.com)

Comment: That does look like it might do what I want, but it costs $379 so I'm guessing that's more high-powered than I ultimately need. Thank you though!

Comment: Did you read the linked page in my first comment? The Community Release of `cpdf` is free!

Comment: Ah, I got lost on a different page within there and didn't read your first page carefully enough. Sorry about that!

Comment: @user3439894 why not answer this - your comment seems more a proper answer

Comment: @bmike, I posted what I did as a comment because by itself I'd consider it to be a link-only answer had I posted it as an answer.  Even David thought it was a $379 app because he got lost on a link from the link and didn't read the community release was free. Had I the time at that moment to expound on it and also include a short script that could accomplish the task I would have posted an answer rather then a comment. (I actually was going to post an answer with a script later but it just fell through the cracks.)

Comment: Thanks so much @user3439894 - it’s here which is much better than never posting

Comment: @bmike, I've added an answer.

Comment: @David, couldn't you split your large PDF file after every 4 pages, into 10 separate files. By-passing the one-page, 0ne-file segment?

Comment: @jmh, David was using **Automator** to split the **PDF** _document_, which has no _options_ for the split and only creates individual _files_, one for each _page_, and why he was looking for a way to combine four at a time and named for each _student_. If you have read my answer you'd see he doesn't need to first split the scanned **PDF** _document_, it's a totally unnecessary step using the _tool_ I suggested along with the **shell script**. It creates a new **PDF** _document_ named for each _student_ directly from the original scanned **PDF** _document_. **No muss no fuss!**

Comment: @user3439894  my method avoided splitting the big file into 40 1 page files using Automater. And then merging them back together in 10 files. He scans each test into a large file. So every 4 pages represent a single test. Just split the original file 4 pages at a time. one simple task with no scripting. And the app is free!!.

Comment: @jmh, Doesn't really matter that the app is free, so is the one in my answer and it also doesn't split the original scanned PDF into 40 files either. What matters is, sans his original scanning, he's looking for a completely automated process, if possible, to do the rest of what need to be done within the context of what was expressed in the OP. As far as I can tell, PDFsam Basic can't fully automate the process. So it splits the file in the given number of pages but then he has to rename each file to the students name. IMO your answer doesn't fully provide what David is asking for. Mine does!

Comment: We all have a right to our opinions.

Comment: @user3439894 Yes it does matter that the App is free. If it was $20 it could make a big difference to the OP.  But since it is free he can just use it for this or other tasks. It's a very useful tool and I'd suggest he downlod it anyway.

Comment: @user3439894  But i will admit if OP is going to use this more than once then the entering names of students in your script gives it the advantage for doing the task multiple times with the same class of students.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the third-party *command line tool*, `cpdf`, and *script* the process of creating the separate **PDF** *documents* for each *student*.

Have a look at: [Coherent PDF Command Line Tools Community Release](http://community.coherentpdf.com/)

- [Download pre-built cpdf tool](https://github.com/coherentgraphics/cpdf-binaries/archive/master.zip) (This is a direct download link. Building from source is available from link on main page linked above.)
- A comprehensive user manual for the PDF tools can be found as a [PDF document](http://www.coherentpdf.com/cpdfmanual.pdf), or [browsable online](http://www.coherentpdf.com/cpdfmanual/cpdfmanual.html).
- **Note:** the **Community Release** version of **Coherent PDF Command Line Tools** is **free**.

There is no need to first extract the the scanned **PDF** *document* into individual *files* to then combine them as the following *example* **shell script** *code* extracts the *pages* from the scanned **PDF** *document* four *pages* at a time while naming each new **PDF** *document* for each *student*:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

    # Replace e.g. "Student 01", etc. with the students name
    # in the order required as scanned in the PDF document.

my_students=("Student 01" "Student 02" "Student 03" "Student 04" "Student 05" "Student 06" "Student 07" "Student 08" "Student 09" "Student 10")

    # Replace "/path/to/scanned.pdf" with the 
    # actual pathname of the scanned document.

scanned_document="/path/to/scanned.pdf"

    # NOTE: If cpdf is not in your PATH, then use its fully
    #       qualified pathname, e.g: /use/local/bin/cpdf

x=1
y=4
for this_student in "${my_students[@]}"; do
    cpdf "${scanned_document}" $x-$y -o "${this_student}.pdf"
    x=$(( x + 4 ))
    y=$(( y + 4 ))
done
```

---

To use this **shell script** in **Terminal**, first run the following *compound command*:

```
f="processpdf"; touch "$f"; open -e "$f"; chmod u+x "$f"
```

Then in the *document* that opens, **TextEdit** by *default*, copy and paste the *example* **shell script** *code* into it, make the appropriate edits, and then save it.

It can now be used in **Terminal** using e.g. `./processpdf` or `/path/to/processpdf` or if placed in a location that's within the `PATH`, then simply, e.g.: `processpdf`

Note: As *coded* the new  **PDF** *documents* are created in the **PWD** in **Terminal**. You can add e.g. `/path/to/` to `"${this_student}.pdf"`, e.g., `"/path/to/${this_student}.pdf"` if you want.

If you need/want to apply this to a **Run Shell Script** *action* in **Automator**, instead of regular **shell script** usage, let me know an I can update the answer.

In either case, if you want to pass the *script* a *file* with the *names* of the *students*, instead of using an *array*, as presently *coded*, that is doable too.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **shell script** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. As an example, as presently *coded*, the  new **PDF** *documents* will overwrite existing *documents* of the same *name*  without warning.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You could skip that first step where you split the large PDF into one page to one file. Then take your large PDF and split it after every four pages into 10 different files. This basically undoes what you did first. The app [PDFsam](https://pdfsam.org) will split a PDF into files after every x pages. [PDFSam](https://pdfsam.org) stands for PDF Split and Merge.